# Selenium webdriver NoSuchElementException s

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this question has been asked a million times before but as far as I can tell from those threads this code should be right so I would appreciate someone taking at look at it.  The goal here is to create a bot that will buy an out of stock item when it returns but I am testing it on [this](https://krikzz.com/our-products/cartridges/everdrive-gg-x7.html).  I am using JupyterLap and anaconda.

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
import chromedriver_binary

wd.Chrome().implicitly_wait(60)

wd.Chrome().get("https://krikzz.com/our-products/cartridges/everdrive-gg-x7.html")

add_to_cart_button = wd.Chrome().find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[2]/button")
```

[picture of error after running program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyg3z.png)

Comment: The obvious explanation is that the element _does not exist_.   The code is fine, as far as I can see.  Either the xpath is wrong, or the element is legitimately absent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use `find_element_by_css_selector`.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver as wd
import chromedriver_binary

driver = wd.Chrome().implicitly_wait(60)

driver.get("https://krikzz.com/our-products/cartridges/everdrive-gg-x7.html")
sleep(5)

add_to_cart_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.card__button")
```

Comment: For some reason it now opens two windows one that works and one that doesn't.  Not entirely sure what the reason is but this does seem to have fixed the original problem so thank you.

Comment: That's because the program repeats the code `wd.Chrome()`. 
I changed the code. So please check it out.